# Multiple Joins in SQL

Tags: mysql, join

I've been having a crazy time trying to make this SQL work.

Basically what I'm trying to do is get the count for how many rooms are currently booked today by room type. So far, I've been able to use a join statement with table1 and table2 to get the total rooms booked overall for the current date, but I can't find a way to link the 4 tables and basically create a list of available room types by roomtype_id. The part that confuses me the most is table4 has a new entry for each room, so in this example roomtype_id "1" has two rooms and roomtype_id "2" has one room.

The end result I would like to get to would say: 
Green Room has 1 room available,
Blue Room has 1 room available. 
 (pretending today is the 11th of August since there is one booking for room_type "1" on the 11th)

I have 4 tables,

table1:
bookings_id    room_type_id
1                     1

table2:
booking_id      booking_date
1                     2013-08-11

table3:
roomtype_id    type_name
1                     Green Room
2                     Blue Room

table4:
room_id          roomtype_id
1                     1
2                     1
3                     2
 Hopefully I wasn't too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

try out this..

```
select * from table1 join
table2 on table1.bookings_id  = table2.bookings_id join
table4 on table1.room_type_id  = table4.roomtype_id join
table3 on table1.room_type_id  = table3.roomtype_id and table3.roomtype_id  = table4.roomtype_id
```